# Is it possible to digitally sign data from a web page in iOS safari?

Tags: javascript, iphone, security, ipad, certificate

I was looking all over and couldn't get a direct and clear answer. Is it possible to sign a document from Javascript code running in a web application (Safari)? I wish to use a certificate from the iPhone built-in certificate store.

I found a similar post which was not answered: [Working with certificates in web applications for Apple iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782241/working-with-certificates-in-web-applications-for-apple-ios)

Thanks!
Yoash

Comment: I doubt Apple would give a web browser access to the private keys stored on the device, because that would be some terrible security, but I really have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just been looking through some older questions (just in case somebody else stumbles across this) and I can say that No, this is definitely not possible. The only way to achieve something along these lines would be to create a phonegap plugin which handles this for you and distribute your web application as a phonegap application.